# Basic SQL aggregate query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `employee` table, employees may have multiple peripherals. I want to bring back all employees that have a peripheral of type 1 or 2, but that don't have any others, and vice versa (i.e. have a peripheral of type other than 1 or 2 but not have any peripherals of 1 or 2). For each of these employees, there should be a flag to show which of the two categories/product types they have.

This query works, but feels a bit verbose:

```
SELECT employee_id,
       has_screen,
       has_keyboard
FROM
(
    SELECT e.employee_id,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN ep.type IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END has_screen,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN ep.type > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END has_keyboard
    FROM employee e
    JOIN employee_peripheral ep
    ON e.employee_id = ep.employee_id
    GROUP BY e.employee_id
) T
WHERE has_screen <> has_keyboard
```

Comment: I did think try that, but I could reference the alias in my `where`. So I had to re-do the `SUM(...` etc. in the `where` again.Which seemed too much. See the following for a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715462/sql-use-alias-in-where-statement

Comment: ^ **couldn't*** reference

Comment: Why is there a `SUM`? Couldn't `CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN ep.type IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END has_screen` be simplified to `CASE WHEN ep.type IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END has_screen`? (Same for `has_keyboard`.)

Comment: Apologies, I think the query was missing a `GROUP BY`. But, basically, @BCdotWEB - I need to say "there exists any peripheral of type 1 or 2 for each employee". Not, "for each record in the join is it type 1 or 2". I need 1 row per employee. I think my lack of GROUP BY probably threw you off.

Answer (score 1):

### BOOL values

Your outer case statements convert a value to itself. `SUM(CASE WHEN type IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0` is TRUE or FALSE, which are equivalent to 1 and 0.

### WHERE vs HAVING

WHERE will filter rows from the input, which means that you can't use an aggregate. [HAVING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) filters after the aggregation, which means you can drop the outer query.

### Unnecessary JOIN

You are only using the `employee_id` from `employee`, which is present in `employee_peripheral`

### Resulting query

```
SELECT employee_id,
SUM(CASE WHEN type IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AS has_screen,
SUM(CASE WHEN type > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AS has_keyboard
FROM employee_peripheral
GROUP BY employee_id
HAVING (SUM(CASE WHEN type IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0) <> (SUM(CASE WHEN type > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0)
```

Comment: 1) I assume the employee can have more than one peripheral in (1,2) and more than one >2 (might be odd in what it would mean, but certainly possible from database perspective), so the SUM(...) > 0 check is necessary. 2) With the subquery in place, the enter thing is more readable to me - the subquery provides analytics with computations and the outer query is an actual search. Of course both versions work and a smart query parser (like SQL Server) optimizes it well. 3) Agree that employee join is indeed unnecessary.

Comment: @Misza 1) ? I still have the SUM(...) > 0, I just use the result of that expression rather than wrapping it in a CASE. 2) Yes, a subquery or CTE to define has_screen and has_keyboard in one place could be considered more readable

Comment: In what SQL dialect can you simply write "SELECT (int expression) > 0 AS has_something"? And what data type this expression supposedly returns? I'm trying in SQL Server and I'm getting syntax error on the ">" sign.